# Error al realizar predicción con ETS

Tags: python, python-3.7, predicción, timeseries

Muy buenos dias a todos. Estoy tratando de hacer una predicción usando ETS.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sktime.forecasting.ets import AutoETS

datos = [21.5294, 21.5228, 21.5289, 21.5096, 21.506, 21.5119, 21.5173, 21.5308, 21.5355, 21.5181, 21.5, 21.4972, 21.5067, 21.5149, 21.4994, 21.4967, 21.4774, 21.4662, 21.4752, 21.4858, 21.4581, 21.4398, 21.4385, 21.4471, 21.4399, 21.444, 21.4555, 21.4366, 21.4402, 21.4371, 21.4317, 21.4342, 21.411, 21.4174, 21.4149, 21.4151, 21.4186, 21.4411, 21.4569, 21.4628, 21.448, 21.4468, 21.4357, 21.4329, 21.4543, 21.4429, 21.4478, 21.4423, 21.4536, 21.4416, 21.4384, 21.4378, 21.4622, 21.4413, 21.4315, 21.4419, 21.4323, 21.429, 21.4103, 21.4194, 21.4364, 21.4245, 21.4348, 21.4276, 21.4113, 21.4235, 21.407, 21.412, 21.4263, 21.431, 21.4362, 21.432, 21.4445, 21.4487, 21.4623, 21.4766, 21.4785, 21.4891, 21.4869, 21.4903, 21.4839, 21.4856, 21.4909, 21.5048, 21.5005, 21.4905, 21.4906, 21.4914, 21.5052, 21.4898, 21.5232, 21.5234, 21.5086, 21.5108, 21.5017, 21.5141, 21.5055, 21.4953, 21.4618, 21.4504, 21.4667, 21.4602, 21.453, 21.4497, 21.4446, 21.4308, 21.4347, 21.4512, 21.4675, 21.4675, 21.465, 21.4624, 21.4682, 21.472, 21.4632, 21.4644, 21.4615, 21.4604, 21.4679, 21.4672]
indice = pd.date_range("2020-10-31 23:57:00", periods=len(datos), freq="T")

datos = pd.Series(data=datos, index=indice)
        
datos = datos.asfreq(freq='T')
    
    
pasado = datos[:100]
futuro = datos[100:]
        
        
model_auto = AutoETS(auto=True, initialization_method='heuristic',
                             allow_multiplicative_trend=True, n_jobs=-1, sp=10)
model_auto.fit(pasado)
    
        
lista = list(np.array(range(20))+1)
prediccion = model_auto.predict(lista)
    
    
pasado.plot()
futuro.plot()
prediccion.plot()
plt.show()
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Prediccion]

- La línea azul corresponde a los datos con los que entreno el modelo.
- La línea naranja corresponde a los datos 'futuros'
- La línea verde corresponde a la predicción y debe estar cerca de la línea naranja.

No sé por qué la predicción tiene siempre el mismo valor.

Me gustaría saber tu opinión al respecto. ¿Sabes por qué ocurre esta situación en esta predicción y cómo puedo corregirla?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es un error como tal... La respuesta corta es: *"Se debe al juego de datos que posees"*.

La respuesta larga, es mejor con un ejemplo... imagínate por un momento que tienes otro juego de datos. Si estas de acuerdo podrían ser:

```
datos = [
    30.05251300, 19.14849600, 25.31769200, 27.59143700,
    32.07645600, 23.48796100, 28.47594000, 35.12375300,
    36.83848500, 25.00701700, 30.72223000, 28.69375900,
    36.64098600, 23.82460900, 29.31168300, 31.77030900,
    35.17787700, 19.77524400, 29.60175000, 34.53884200,
    41.27359900, 26.65586200, 28.27985900, 35.19115300,
    42.20566386, 24.64917133, 32.66733514, 37.25735401,
    45.24246027, 29.35048127, 36.34420728, 41.78208136,
    49.27659843, 31.27540139, 37.85062549, 38.83704413,
    51.23690034, 31.83855162, 41.32342126, 42.79900337,
    55.70835836, 33.40714492, 42.31663797, 45.15712257,
    59.57607996, 34.83733016, 44.84168072, 46.97124960,
    60.01903094, 38.37117851, 46.97586413, 50.73379646,
    61.64687319, 39.29956937, 52.67120908, 54.33231689,
    66.83435838, 40.87118847, 51.82853579, 57.49190993,
    65.25146985, 43.06120822, 54.76075713, 59.83447494,
    73.25702747, 47.69662373, 61.09776802, 66.05576122]

indice = pd.date_range("2020-10-31 23:57:00", periods=len(datos), freq="T")

datos = pd.Series(data=datos, index=indice)
        
datos = datos.asfreq(freq='T')
```

De esta manera tendrías un codigo similar a esto:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
    
datos = [
        30.05251300, 19.14849600, 25.31769200, 27.59143700,
        32.07645600, 23.48796100, 28.47594000, 35.12375300,
        36.83848500, 25.00701700, 30.72223000, 28.69375900,
        36.64098600, 23.82460900, 29.31168300, 31.77030900,
        35.17787700, 19.77524400, 29.60175000, 34.53884200,
        41.27359900, 26.65586200, 28.27985900, 35.19115300,
        42.20566386, 24.64917133, 32.66733514, 37.25735401,
        45.24246027, 29.35048127, 36.34420728, 41.78208136,
        49.27659843, 31.27540139, 37.85062549, 38.83704413,
        51.23690034, 31.83855162, 41.32342126, 42.79900337,
        55.70835836, 33.40714492, 42.31663797, 45.15712257,
        59.57607996, 34.83733016, 44.84168072, 46.97124960,
        60.01903094, 38.37117851, 46.97586413, 50.73379646,
        61.64687319, 39.29956937, 52.67120908, 54.33231689,
        66.83435838, 40.87118847, 51.82853579, 57.49190993,
        65.25146985, 43.06120822, 54.76075713, 59.83447494,
        73.25702747, 47.69662373, 61.09776802, 66.05576122]
    
indice = pd.date_range("2020-10-31 23:57:00", periods=len(datos), freq="T")
    
datos = pd.Series(data=datos, index=indice)
    
datos = datos.asfreq(freq='T')
          
          
pasado = datos[:48]
futuro = datos[47:]

              
modelo = ETSModel(datos, error="add", trend="add", seasonal="add",
                    damped_trend=True, seasonal_periods=4)
#modelo_fit = modelo.fit(maxiter=10000)
fit = modelo.fit()
    
print(fit.summary())
    
pred = fit.get_prediction(start='2020-11-01 00:44:00', end='2020-11-01 01:04:00')
    
df = pred.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
    
    
simulated = fit.simulate(anchor="end", nsimulations=10, repetitions=100)

for i in range(simulated.shape[1]):
  simulated.iloc[:,i].plot(label='_', color='gray', alpha=0.1)
      
df["mean"].plot(label='mean prediction')
df["pi_lower"].plot(linestyle='--', color='tab:cyan', label='95% interval')
df["pi_upper"].plot(linestyle='--', color='tab:cyan', label='_')

pred.endog.plot(label='data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Obtendrías un resultado de este tipo:

[image: Ejemplo: simulación_1]

Tus datos estan representados en color anaranjado. El modelo ETS, estima un promedio de los datos en azul, y un rango en el que los datos pueden variar basado en la media (que son  las lineas intermitentes de color cian). Después (en la predicción) el modelo realiza una simulación tratando de pronosticar, 10 pasos adelante, y realiza 100 intentos (son las lineas grises).

En este caso particular, el modelo se ajusta muy bien a los datos... ¡pero claro!, es un ejemplo de libro de texto, así que funcionara a la perfección *—en la practica diaria la teoría es otra*.

El modelo ETS al usarse para predecir, cuenta con varias funciones  disponibles:

- **forecast**: Realiza predicciones a partir de muestra
- **predict**: Predicciones en muestra y fuera de muestra
- **simulate**: Ejecuta simulaciones del modelo de espacio de estados
- **get_prediction**: Predicciones en muestra y fuera de muestra, así como intervalos de predicción.

En tu caso los datos, son a falta de otra palabra estocásticos a los ojos del modelo y este modelo en particular, le cuesta generar o decidirse hacia donde pueden ir los datos en el futuro, así que estima una media, unos rangos superiores e inferiores en los cuales pueden estar los datos en el futuro.

Tomemos el mismo código, y solo variemos los datos, tendrías algo asi:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel

    
pasado = datos[:100]
futuro = datos[99:]
print(futuro)
        
modelo = ETSModel(datos, error="add", trend="add", seasonal="add",
              damped_trend=True, seasonal_periods=4)
#modelo_fit = modelo.fit(maxiter=10000)
fit = modelo.fit()

print(fit.summary())

#prediccion = modelo_fit.get_prediction(start='2020-11-01 01:37:00', end='2020-11-01 01:57:00')
pred = fit.get_prediction(start='2020-11-01 01:36:00', end='2020-11-01 01:56:00')

df = pred.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)




simulated = fit.simulate(anchor="end", nsimulations=20, repetitions=100)
for i in range(simulated.shape[1]):
  simulated.iloc[:,i].plot(label='_', color='gray', alpha=0.1)


df["mean"].plot(label='mean prediction')
df["pi_lower"].plot(linestyle='--', color='tab:cyan', label='95% interval')
df["pi_upper"].plot(linestyle='--', color='tab:cyan', label='_')
pred.endog.plot(label='data')

pasado.plot(label='Pasado')
futuro.plot(label='Futuro')



plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Simulación]

Después de los datos de entrenamiento (en color verde), sigue una especie de burbuja (lo contenido entre las lineas punteadas de color cian), que es una estimación (segun el modelo), de el lugar donde podrían estar lo datos en el futuro, así que la linea que te aparece generalmente con el mismo valor, es el promedio estimado de los valores futuros que augura el modelo. O sea, según los datos, el modelo no se logra ajustar con precisión a los datos que tienes en la variable futuro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Futuros]

Un modelo que se puede ajustar (definitivamente... quizá) mejor a los datos podría ser SARIMA o SARIMAX, lo mejor es buscar (para los casos anteriores) algún mecanismo/libreria que ajuste los valores order=(p,d,q) y seasonal_order=(P,D,Q,s) de manera automática (aunque el coste computacional puede empezar a elevarse).

Claro existen muchos más modelos, Mathematica cuenta con una función (que en este momento no recuerdo) y te busca el modelo y el juego de parámetros que mejor se adecua a los datos. Quizá Python en algún lugar tenga algo similar *—si es así, me encantaría conocerlo.*

[image: SARIMA]